# Is Axios.all available in nestjs?

Tags: axios, nestjs

I would like to make a method in service which handle multiple requests at once in my NestJS project.
Right now what I used is the HTTPService from @nestjs/axios
I tried to found resources on the internet about axios.all for nestjs, but I can't really get the exact things I want for NestJS.
So I would like to ask that does Axios.all() exist in the nestjs?

Answer (score 1):

You can see on `@nestjs/axios`'s `package.json` ([here](https://github.com/nestjs/axios/blob/766a5fa3debf97201115ea5d38ed509bbc087303/package.json#L21)) which version of `axios` is beign used by that lib. If that version support Axios.all, then it's available. You could retrive the axios instance using  `this.httpService.axiosRef()`

Answer (score 1):

`axios.all` and `axios.spread` are [deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2260). Just use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).